# method maya doMenuComponentSelection

Tags: python, methods, components, selection, mel

I was wondering where to find the source code of the doMenuComponentSelection() method. Thank you

I searched for Maya files but couldn't find them. I just want to see the source of this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the method on github, https://github.com/elrond79/mayaSettings/blob/master/2009-x64/zooScripts/dagMenuProc.mel#L977

```
global proc doMenuComponentSelection(string $item, string $mask)
//
// Changes the selection/display state on this object to allow
// selection of the specified selection mask type.
{
    string $selectCmd;

    if (`selectMode -q -object`) {
        hilite $item;
        selectType -ocm -alc false;
        $selectCmd = "selectType -ocm -" + $mask + " true;";
    } else {
        selectType -ocm -alc false;
        $selectCmd = "selectType -" + $mask + " true;";
        if (!`selectMode -q -preset`) {
            $selectCmd = $selectCmd + "hilite " + $item + ";";
        }
    }
    eval $selectCmd;
}
```

Comment: you are welcome. if this answer helped, please accept it :)

Comment: excuse me . I had another question. Can methods like selectType be accessed? In any language written. Thanks